# Windows 10 - OpenSSH Forward Agent Loading Keys but not Forwarding, SSH-Agent seems to be ignoring loaded keys

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

## Problem:

##### I am trying to use OpenSSH Agent in Windows 10 Pro. It is loading the keys but not forwarding to the host.

## Goal:

##### I am attempting to get `ssh-agent` to work in Windows so I don't have to keep entering my passphrase for my private key (with the ultimate goal of getting this to work with VS Code Remote-SSH Extension as well as on the command line).

## What I've Tried:

I am using Windows 10 Pro 21H2 build 19044.1865. I have `OpenSSH` installed. In `Powershell` (admin mode), I use `ssh-add` to add my private key and confirm by doing `ssh-add -L` which shows the key is loaded (X'd out in example):

```
ssh-add -L
ssh-ed25519 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (redacted)
```

I then attempt `ssh -A username@serverip` and it prompts me for my passphrase. The expected behavior is that it would not prompt me for my passphrase, it would simply obtain the key from the ssh-agent service. I have tried both rsa and ed25519 keys formatted as OpenSSH keys with the same result.

If I enter my passphrase I immediately connect. I have tried all the suggestions I could find online including:

- killing all `ssh-agent` processes shown in task manager and restarting
- starting and restarting the OpenSSH Authentication Agent
- fixing the permissions on my keys so only I as owner have access

It appears that the `ssh-agent` has loaded the key but is simply not passing it on to my server for some reason. Using the `-v` (verbose) option shows no attempt to use ssh-agent forwarding. I have used [putty/pageant](https://www.putty.org/) successfully and have even tried  [wsl-ssh-pageant](https://github.com/benpye/wsl-ssh-pageant) which seems to work, loading my key from pageant (the Pageant keys viewable as loaded after doing ssh-add -L) but they are ignored when I attempt a connection (again nothing in the verbose output shows attempt to use the `ssh-agent`). The OpenSSH agent is clearly running in Windows services.

Any suggestions or help ? Thank you.

Comment: Have the same problem, probably this is not implemented yet.